# Disable joining multiple windows to one icon in unity panel

Tags: unity, panel, window-manager

I don't want multiple open windows of the same program to be joined in one icon. How can I disable that to get one icon per window?

Answer (score 3):

The Unity laucher doesn't support such a one icon per window mode.